# how to override vuetify style for components globaly

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am tring to set my buttons with vuetify but, I don't want each time to set the background color and the style of the button, or with any other vuetify component. 
what is the best practice to set global style for the component like buttons chips avatar ect...
i now i can create my own component for that but then there is no reason using vuetify.
I have a nuxt project but the same apply to vue

Comment: This might help: [Easily change the colors of your application programmatically](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/)

Comment: Customizing theme is handy for colors and breakpoints. If you need to set certain style properties like 'rounded' on VBtn by default, it's still easiest to make your own wrapper components for vuetify components. Vuetify does a lot under the hood with animations, a11y, easy customization, so running your own custom implementation would still be a lot more work than simply extending a VBtn and setting a prop. Wouldn't call that 'no reason to use' ;p

Comment: I change it already, but i did not see a part of overriding the default components like the buttons. maybe going to the root css file and change the btn class or somthing like this and in this way i cann't change any other functionality.

Comment: i will look at wrapper components, but is the a way the that i will be able to use the button component anywhere in my project without the import statment? if you can also send a link for example this will be very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Might be not the best practice, but this is how I'm doing it:

1. Create file for your global style (e.g. `main.scss`) In your assets folder.
2. Plug it in nuxt.config.js as so: `css: ["~assets/styles/main.scss"]`
3. Add class to your app root element (e.g. in default layout)
4. Create `_vuetify.scss` for overwriting Vutify styles and import it in `main.scss`
5. Write your Vuetify styles in scope of app root class for gaining selector weight.

   .app .v-toolbar { 
        background-color: red;  }

If this is too much, or as a quick solution you can just write your global styles in default layout, scoping with app root class.

Comment: ok, i will try. 
I am not sure this is the best practice but i thought about adding to the layout.vue an scss that will overwrite the vuetify style but this will have to import to each layout which, is fine cause usually you don't have many like that.